# Paginate entries with 'page' query parameter?

Tags: pagination

Is it possible to use a `page` query parameter for paginating entries with `{% paginate %}` instead of a dynamic segment?

So instead of `http://example.com/articles/p2` i would like to use `http://example.com/articles?page=2`.

This would simplify interoperability with client side MVC frameworks because the query parameter would be clearly separated from a dynamic route for a single entry in `articles` (i.e. `http://example.com/articles/a-single-article`).

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to not use `{% paginate %}` altogether and instead calculate `limit` and `offset` for `craft.entries.find(...)` manually from `craft.request.getQuery("page")`. I hope there is an easier way?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `pageTrigger` setting just changes the segment. Looking at Craft's source, as best I can tell the segments are the only thing that can be used with the built in `paginate` tags. Christian, were you able to figure something out? I hesitate to resort to writing a bunch of custom code to read/update `craft.request`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what are you searching for:

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#pageTrigger